# Как на странице сайта вместо серой горизонтальной разделительной линии сделать толстую (3 мм) горизонтальную разделительную линию зеленого цвета?

Tags: wordpress

Как на странице [сайта](http://www.01.org.ua/pro-fond/spivrobitniki/) (сайт сделан на WordPress)  вместо серой горизонтальной разделительной линии между сотрудниками сделать толстую (3 мм) горизонтальную разделительную линию зеленого цвета?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант изменить border-bottom у класса .employee.

Оригинал:

```
.employee {
   display: flex;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Изменённый пример:

```
.employee {
   display: flex;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #007f00;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

При этом только убрать/изменить внутрений класс employee у "БОЛОШИНА ОЛЬГА ВІТАЛІЇВНА".
Результат какого-либо изменения CSS на текущей странице можно смотреть, правя CSS через консоль разработчика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]